# Remove rows in dataframe that do not contain ALL items in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of letters:

```
letters = ['E', 'H', 'T', 'D']
```

I have a dataframe with the following rows:

```
    letter_1 letter_2 letter_3 letter_4 letter_5   word
0        D        E        B        U        T    DEBUT
1        D        E        B        U        G    DEBUG
2        B        E        G        E        T    BEGET
3        D        E        P        T        H    DEPTH
4        D        U        V        E        T    DUVET
```

I am trying to filter out all rows that do not contain **ALL** of the items in the letters list.

Comment: so, what would be the output? Row 3 only?

Comment: @mozway yes that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use set operations:

```
df[df.filter(like='letter').agg(set, axis=1) >= set(letters)]
```

or using the "word":

```
df[df['word'].agg(set) >= set(letters)]
```

output:

```
  letter_1 letter_2 letter_3 letter_4 letter_5   word
3        D        E        P        T        H  DEPTH
```

Comment: I implemented your second solution, however if there are duplicate items in the list, this does not work since sets do not take duplicates. Is there a way to account for this?

Comment: You could combine a set and a Counter?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) and broadcasting (this performs all comparisons and ensure there is at least 1 match for each letter):

```
m = (df.filter(like='letter').to_numpy()==np.array(letters)[:,None,None]
     ).any(2).all(0)
df[m]
```

output:

```
  letter_1 letter_2 letter_3 letter_4 letter_5   word
3        D        E        P        T        H  DEPTH
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `numpy.in1d`

```
df[df.word.apply(lambda x: np.in1d(letters, list(x)).all())]
 
  letter_1 letter_2 letter_3 letter_4 letter_5   word
3        D        E        P        T        H  DEPTH
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
df[df['word'].apply(lambda x: all(s in x for s in letters))]
```

| index | letter_1 | letter_2 | letter_3 | letter_4 | letter_5 | word |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | D | E | P | T | H | DEPTH |